JAX-WS: differences between "jaxws-rt" and "rt" in "com.sun.xml.ws" Maven group
I'm trying to figure out the differences between jaxws-rt and rt.  I've compared both the two poms and the content of the jars but this led to more questions rather than answers.  They have many similarities, for example the pom description says:

jaxws-rt: JAX-WS Runtime with module descriptor
rt: JAX-WS Reference Implementation Runtime

Both jars (v4.0.2) contain a module-info.class (of course!) so why "with module descriptor"?
Strangely they refer to different JAXB implementations (jaxws-rt uses jaxb-impl, rt uses jaxb-runtime); jaxws-rt has more packages.  Even a third module exists: jaxws-ri but its packaging type is pom, not jar, so it is less interesting.
Which of the two should I use?
